Reactive power and voltage relationship curve
This is from Kundur's book Power System Stability and Control, subsection 2.1.2 Voltage Stability and Voltage Collapse. A simple system consists of a constant voltage source (\$E_S\$) supplying a load (\$Z_{LD}\$) through a series impedance (\$Z_{LN}\$) as shown below.

Here we use \$\cos\phi=0.95\$ lag and \$\tan\theta=10.0\$. The expression for current in above figure is $$\tilde{I}=\frac{\tilde{E}_S}{\tilde{Z}_{LN}+\tilde{Z}_{LD}}$$ where current and voltage are in phasors and $$\tilde{Z}_{LN}=Z_{LN}\angle\theta,\quad\tilde{Z}_{LD}=Z_{LD}\angle\phi$$ The magnitude of the current is given by $$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{F}}\frac{E_S}{Z_{LN}}$$ where $$F=1+\left[\frac{Z_{LD}}{Z_{LN}}\right]^2+2\left[\frac{Z_{LD}}{Z_{LN}}\right]\cos(\theta-\phi)$$ The magnitude of the receiving end voltage is given by $$V_R=Z_{LD}I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{F}}\frac{Z_{LD}}{Z_{LN}}E_S$$ The power supplied to the load is $$P_R=V_RI\cos\phi=\frac{Z_{LD}}{F}\left[\frac{E_S}{Z_{LN}}\right]^2\cos\phi$$ and the corresponding reactive power is $$Q_R=V_RI\sin\phi=\frac{Z_{LD}}{F}\left[\frac{E_S}{Z_{LN}}\right]^2\sin\phi$$
I am trying to reproduce this figure, a relationship between \$V_R\$ and \$Q_R\$ at a fixed value of \$P_R\$.

Are above curves parametric? If so, what's the parameter? Surely it's not \$Z_{LN}/Z_{LD}\$, since constant \$P_R\$ means constant \$Z_{LN}/Z_{LD}\$. So, I tried to find direct relationship between \$V_R/E_S\$ and \$Q_R/P_{RMAX}\$. Notice that, when power factor is 1 we have $$P_{RMAX}=\frac{E_S^2}{Z_{LN}(2+2\cos\theta)}$$ and hence $$\frac{Q_R}{P_{RMAX}}=\frac{Z_{LD}}{Z_{LN}}\frac{(2+2\cos\theta)\sin\phi}{F}$$ Since $$\frac{V_R}{E_S}=\frac{Z_{LD}}{Z_{LN}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{F}}$$ we get $$\frac{Q_R}{P_{RMAX}}=K\left[\frac{V_R}{E_S}\right]^2$$ for some constant $$K=\frac{Z_{LN}}{Z_{LD}}(2+2\cos\theta)\sin\phi$$ Obviously the obtained relationship between \$V_R/E_S\$ and \$Q_R/P_{RMAX}\$ is different from the given figure. Did I miss something? What is the correct way to reproduce the above curves?

https://www.irjet.net/archives/V4/i1/IRJET-V4I115.pdf
